# Relation "migrations" already exists (SQL: create table "migrations" ("migration" varchar(255) not null, "batch" integer not null)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, migration, psql

Since I move my Laravel database driver from MySQL to PostgreSQL, when I run `php artisan migrate` I kept getting:

[image]

Can someone please tell me why ? Or how do I avoid that ?

Comment: Have you tried ```php artisan migrate:rollback```

Comment: Seems you have previously run migrations existing in the database. You could try `php artisan migrate:refresh` to completely remove the previous migragions and re-run. It the previously run migrations have been changed you may get errors, in that case access your database through a tool like phpMyAdmin equivalent for PostgreSQL and drop all tables from the database. Then try to run `php artisan migrate`